# What alternatives do exists for properly squeezing lemons?

Tags: equipment, utensils, lemon, lemon-juice

This happened to me often when I go to some restaurants or be on a visit to somebody place. It just happen that I want to add some lemon to my soup or use it as an addition to my meals but they do not have access to a lemon crusher. Is that the name of the tool?.

I've seen people used forks, spoons and just their thumb for squeezing the juice of the lemon. But is there a method which has proven to work the best to take out all of the juice without trying to make much force with the hands or something?. Is there a tool that can be carried on maybe portable for this purposes?.

Answer (score 3):

A [lemon wedge squeezer](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=lemon%20wedge%20squeezer&t=ffnt&ia=recipes) may be what you want.
They are [image: compact]
and the lemon wedge [image: is placed like this].

(Pictures from Amazon.com)

Comment: I was not aware that such device existed. Have you ever used it? Does it ensure that all the juice is extracted from the lemon?

Comment: I have used some that are well-made and work well enough on quarter wedges; others I have seen seem to be too flimsy to squeeze wet tissue.  You get what you pay for.  Personally, I normally squeeze with my fingers.

Answer (score 3):

If I serve lemon to be squeezed over a dish. I segment it the other way..(from pole to pole, not around the equator). Then cut the core off, leaving  one or more squared-off segments in the piece. I can then pick out remaining pips with a fork.

If cut in this direction, it's easy to squeeze out all the juice in the segments by hand, no tools required.

Comment: Yes!! One problem, though: you really need to get rid of the seeds before squeezing, or you could end up with a depth charge in your opaque sauce :)

Comment: @rackandboneman True.. I hold the wedge up to the light to check. But, I admit, it's not very 'refined'.

Comment: @RobinBetts Actually I felt that my problem is that using bare hands is something which I would like to avoid.